# Machine learning with python package chatterbot

Tags: python, machine-learning, chatterbot

Entire chatterbot we feed the bot with data and it responds accordingly. But why they say its a machine learning dialogue conversation. I don't see any machine learning in that.

At least if bot doesn't have data what user speaks, if it learns and speaks automatically next time then we can accept machine learning is there.

Can any one enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that ChatterBot learns new responses based on the conversations it engages in.

Additionally, ChatterBot uses search algorithms and classification algorithms to return appropriate responses to the input it receives. A form of "reinforcement" can also be used to teach the chat bot to respond with statements that are more commonly demonstrated as responses to particular inputs.

For reference: [What kinds of machine learning does ChatterBot use?](http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-kinds-of-machine-learning-does-chatterbot-use)